# Check if exist Files uploaded, show button to view and download files

Tags: laravel, view, datatable, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I have a datatable in a .blade.php view with my documents that I uploaded, and I have a **button** to view the document and To Download the doc.
But when I'm **not uploading a file**, just a title and a description, I want that buttons to view and download disappear, because they don't have a utility and display a error in my app if the user try to click on.

Heres is my table:

[image]

So, theres a way to fix this? I tried to do a @if in my table but doesn't work.

Here is my .blade file:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.  You can use `@if` or even a simple conditional within the table to do exactly what you want.

I don't know what your conditions are since I don't know what you tried, but the general path would be to check if the 'utility' or the file exists on the object.  If so, show the view and download buttons.  If not, have them disappear.  If you don't want anything to show up at all, you can do this easily with css:

I'm writing pseudo code since I can't copy your image code:

```
<td>
   // conditionally hide the whole thing based on some condition using 'collapse' or 'hidden' class
   <a href='posts/...' class="{{isset($data->file) ? '': 'collapse'}}">
         <i class='fa-eye ....'>
   </a>
 <td>
```

And same thing with the next `<td>` for download.

If you want to display something, perhaps like an indicator that you have a title and description, but no file you can use `@if` and provide conditional html for that `<td>`:

```
<td>
   @if(isset($data->file))
       <a href='posts/...' >
         <i class='fa-eye ....'>
       </a>
   @else
       There is no file 
   @endif
<td>
```